# How to connect to database through ODBC

Tags: c#, odbc

```
private void Form7_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=true;database=EDIXfer");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select EDIScheduleID from ETAProcessSchedule", cn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[x][0].ToString());
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine, but in case of OLEDB or ODBC, it's not working (namespaces added for both OLEDB and ODBC).

```
using System.Data.Odbc;

private void Form7_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Integrated Security=true;database=EDIXfer");
    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("select EDIScheduleID from ETAProcessSchedule", cn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[x][0].ToString());
    }
}
```

How to correctly connect to database using ODBC?

Comment: The classes and libraries for ODBC are different. And for OLEDB, even the approach will be different. Please share your existing code for ODBC and we can help you correct mistakes in it, if any.

Answer (score 0):

This might help,

```
using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand(
    "SELECT ColumnWord FROM OkieTable WHERE MagicKey = ?", con))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var", paramWord);

    using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string word = reader.GetString(0);
            // Word is from the database. Do something with it.
        }
    }
}
```